# Regex up to 4-digit number and/or up to 4 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that allows UP TO 4 digit number AND/OR 4 decimal places.

ONLY allowed format examples (I'm just using only 1s to make the format looks simple, it all should be [0-9])

```
1 
1.1
1.11
1.111
1.1111
11
11.1
11.11
11.111
11.1111
111
111.1
111.11
111.111
111.1111
1111
1111.1
1111.11
1111.111
1111.1111
```

So far the closest one I've gotten --

```
"^[0-9]{0,4}(?:.[0-9]{0,4}$)"
```

It works pretty good when I enter numbers + decimals.
However, if I just enter numbers without decimals, I can enter 4+ number digits, which it should not.

Comment: If this is for live input validation, you need `^[0-9]{0,4}(?:[.][0-9]{0,4})?$`

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! I was a bit close.... jk I wasn't. haha Thank you again!

Comment: `/^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})?$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, If I want to add one more condition that the format should not allow negative numbers.. what's the best way?
Just simply add 
^\-[0-9]{0,4}(?:[.][0-9]{0,4})?$                What do you think?

Comment: `/^\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{0,4})?$/` does not allow negative numbers. If you want to allow them, add an optional `-`, `/^-?\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{0,4})?$/`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just gave you a check mark. But somehow, /^-?\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{0,4})?$/ this doesn't even work at all. ^[0-9]{0,4}(?:[.][0-9]{0,4})?$ this is the only one that follow the format example just fine. Is there anywhere to add a condition do not allow a negative (-) in front of this regex ^[0-9]{0,4}(?:[.][0-9]{0,4})?$

Comment: Tried a few things such as ^-?[0-9]{0,4}(?:[.][0-9]{0,4})?$ but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^[0-9]{0,4}(?:.[0-9]{0,4}$)` only seems to be almost working for you. As `.` is unescaped, it matches any char including digits, and you have an impression it works.

Once you properly escape `.` with a literal `\`, it will stop "working", because this will require a dot.

You need to use

```js
/^\d{0,4}(?:\.\d{0,4})?$/
"^[0-9]{0,4}(?:[.][0-9]{0,4})?$"
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{0,4}` / `\d{4}` - zero to four digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?` - an optional occurrence of a `.` and then zero to four digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is correct, but I would have put `\d{1,4}` instead of `\d{0,4}` in order to avoid strings like `11.` or `.11`

Comment: @Andrea It is not a regex for final validation, it is for  *live input* validation. For final validation, `/^\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$/` must be used.

Comment: Yes, I missed the information about the _live input_. If this is the case of the OP, `\d{0,4}` is absolutely right.

Comment: Here's my solution "/^(\d{0,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{0,4}?)$/"

Comment: @JuanSánchez It is the same as mine, but mine is a bit more efficient. Also, `\d{0,4}?` before `$` makes little sense, it is the same as `\d{0,4}`

Comment: Thank you guys for the good answers! It is live input validation, and I verified Wiktor's regex works great and looks like its clean too.